# Scaling numbers within a dataframe column to the same proportion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a series of numbers of two different magnitudes in a dataframe column.  They are

```
0    154480.429000
1       154.480844
2    154480.433000
3       154.480844
4    154480.433000
......
```

As we can see that above,  I am not sure how to set a condition to scale the small number 154.480844 to have the same order of magnitude as the large one 154480.433000 in dataframe.

How can this be done efficiently with pandas?

Comment: I am wondering what is the purpose of doing this? Is this because '.' has been misplaced or there is any other reason (e.g. textual comparison of strings representing numbers). The approaches could be quite different...

Comment: *"I have a two different numbers..."*: I see three different numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.log10` to determine the scaling factor required. Something like this:

```
v = np.log10(ser).astype(int)
ser * 10 ** (v.max() - v).values

0    154480.429
1    154480.844
2    154480.433
3    154480.844
4    154480.433
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```